# MySQL to Postgres group_by error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

The following query works fine in MySQL (which is **generated by rails**):

```
SELECT
   sum(up_votes) total_up_votes 
FROM
   "answers" 
WHERE
   "answers"."user_id" = 100
ORDER BY
   "answers"."id" ASC
```

Yet it gives the following error in Postgres:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "answers.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

**Edit:** updated query. And here is the Rails model where this query is performed:

```
class User < MyModel
  def top?
    data = self.answers.select("sum(up_votes) total_up_votes").first
    return (data.total_up_votes.present? && data.total_up_votes >= 10)
  end
end
```

Comment: Perhaps there is an alternative method which tells rails there is only one row in the result, and therefore not to add an `order by`?

Comment: Considering how many Rails people use Postgres, I sure hope there is a way. Never had this problem with MySQL.

Comment: Looks like you should be able to use `self.answers.sum(...)` or `.calculate(...)` for this case: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum (I don't use Ruby on Rails, so can't confirm)

Answer (score 2):

The query may execute in MySQL, but I doubt that it "works fine".  It returns only one row, so the ordering is meaningless.

Your question is vague on what you actually want to do, but this should produce the same results as your query, in both databases:

```
SELECT sum(up_votes) as total_up_votes
FROM answers
WHERE user_id = 100;
```

Comment: I updated the question. The queries are generated by Rails automatically. And if I remove the ordering, Rails still tacks on ordering by the id by default. This still doesn't work in Postgres.

Comment: @user3188544 . . . If you add a `group by user_id` to the query, that might convince Rails not to do silly things with the `order by`.  Perhaps it is confused at an aggregation query without a `group by`.  (Note:  total speculation on my part.)